# Edit to replace incorrect tag got rejected. Why?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I just proposed my very first edit on SO, but it got quickly rejected in a peer review, with the reason being that my edits were either not useful in clarifying the question, or were actually actively harmful.

The OP had tagged the question with "regex", although the question clearly involved globbing instead of regexes, so I replaced the "regex" tag with "glob" and slightly reworded the question to reflect this change. I did this after I answered the question.

I understand that perhaps the OP did not understand the distinction between globs and regexes, so I explained that they are two different things in my edit text. Did I do the right thing, or should I have addressed this in a different way?

Comment: This is how you could have done it https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14813593 (edit submitted by me)

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for providing an improved edit for that specific question. I see how you addressed the OP's misconceptions by rephrasing the question in a more generic sense without referencing either regexes or globs. I also see that you corrected grammar and improved style in the same edit (I was originally thinking that maybe those sorts of changes should exist in their own edit, separate from the semantic changes). Anyway, your example was a good illustration for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all: thanks for bringing this up and for trying to improve the quality of post on Stack Overflow.

One [reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14811260) gave this reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

which basically covers why your edit was not correct.

It might be perfectly true that you'll need or they meant glob there and not regex. Without confirmation of the OP you're guessing. And also future visitors facing the same issue as the OP did will probably also falsely assume it is called regex. If you take out that wording that question (and the answer you gave) will be harder to find. Add the tag once you got confirmation on either a comment or because of becoming the accepted answer. I personally wouldn't remove the original tag.

So in the context of the OP your edit might be correct, for the goal of Stack Overflow your edit makes the question harder to find for visitors. If that is a common misconception that glob is not regex and regex is not glob, explain that in your answer.

On the editing itself: I would have only corrected the typos, removed the unneeded use of **Bold** and added some paragraph breaks to make the question less of a wall of text.
I might have left a comment like *isn't that glob what you're after, instead of regex?*.  In the worst case you'll get a reply *My boss told me to use regex, as glob is banned from our project*.

Keep it up!

Comment: *"And also future visitors facing the same issue as the OP did will probably also falsely assume it is called regex. If you take out that wording (and the tag) that question (and the answer you gave) will be harder to find."* Wait, what? We should tag questions incorrectly to help people with similar misunderstandings find them? No.

Comment: @CodyGray reworded a bit. Still feel that *removing* that tag could change intent without confirmation of the OP.

Comment: I'm not trying to defend the suggested edit. It did seem like it was putting words in the OP's mouth, without any real evidence provided why that is, in fact, what they must have meant. But if it is determined that Sam's answer is correct, and the OP actually did mean globs, not regexes, then I think the regex tag should be removed.

Comment: I think it's more important how to change it, rather than the mere change. For example, this edit was approved https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14813593

Comment: Please don't keep wrong tags just because some people misunderstands them.

Comment: @CodyGray, ...using `.../*.txt` in an example is pretty clear evidence that it's glob, rather than regex, syntax intended; a pattern with 0-or-more `/`s, followed by any character and then `txt` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: reworded a bit given the feedback in comments. Is this better @Oriol ?

Comment: @charles You are providing evidence/rationale that was not in the suggested edit message. I have literally no idea whether what you're saying is true or not, because I don't know what a glob even is and I know very little about regular expressions. So I'm not claiming that anyone is wrong here, I was first pointing out a problem I had with Rene's wording, and second a problem that I had with the suggested edit message not providing a sufficient justification for an edit that looked major.